# app to get OpenShift route url and certificate/key pair?

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin

I'm running my app in openshift. I've created a openshift https route.

I'm wondering is there a way that my app can get the route https url and its certificate/key ? is there such an env I can use ?

I'm using openshift-origin 1.4

- Thanks

Comment: For the route you can definitely use the REST API. For the certificate information, if it is your own certificate that you added to the route when exposing the service, then the REST API may possibly allow you to get that as well. You wouldn't be able to get anything related to the certificate if relying on edge termination done by OpenShift using its certificate for the default host name.

Comment: Thanks.Yes,I am using the edge termination done by openshift.The main reason that I need the https key/route url is that I can use the key to sign JWT token in my app.   any suggestion how I can do this?